# laravel 5.8 cannot update value in database

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I tried to delete a user and change the post to other author's,
but i only get a blank page.

url:

> "http://127.0.0.1:8000/backend/admin/8?delete_option=attribute&selected_user=9"

here is my blade

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.destroy', $admin->id) }}" method="DELETE">

                <div class="panel panel-flat">


                    <div class="panel-body ">

                        <div class="col-xs-9">
                            <div class="box">
                                <div class="box-body">
                                    <p>
                                        Anda punya pilihan untuk mengapus user ini
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        ID #{{$admin->id}}: {{$admin->name}}
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Konten yang sudah dibuat Admin ini harus diapakan?
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <input type="radio" name="delete_option" value="delete" checked> Hapus semua konten atas nama admin ini
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        <input type="radio" name="delete_option" value="attribute"> Alihkan konten ke admin lain
                                        <select class="form-control" name="selected_user" id="">
                                              @foreach($user as $admin)
                                              <option value="{{$admin->id}}">{{$admin->name}}</option>
                                              @endforeach
                                        </select>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="box-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Konfirmasi Delete</button>
                                    <a href="{{ route('admin.index') }}" class="btn btn-default">Batalkan</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /basic layout -->
                <!-- /categories -->
            </form>
```

this is my controller

```
  public function destroy(Requests\UserDestroyRequest $request, $id)
    {
        //
      $admin = User::where('id', $id)->first();

      $deleteOption = $request->delete_option;

      $selectedUser = $request->selected_user;

      if($delete_option == "delete"){
        $admin->posts()->delete();
      }

      elseif ($deleteOption == "attribute") {



        $admin->posts()->update( ['author_id' => $selectedUser]);



      }

      $admin->delete();

      return redirect()->route('admin.index')->with('message', 'Admin berhasil dihapus!');
  }

      public function confirm(Requests\UserDestroyRequest $request, $id)
    {
        //
      $admin = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user = User::where('id', '!=', $admin->id)->get(); 
      return view("backend.admin.confirm", compact('admin', 'user'));
  }
```

Anyone know what is the problem which causes the value of author_id in database to not be updated?

Comment: Is the code reporting any Errors? Since, as per my assumption the `$admin->posts()` would resolve into a `Collection` and you are calling the `update` on that collection.

Comment: yes i got new error BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\User::posts()

Comment: whats that mean? @MD.TabishMahfuz

Comment: Have you defined a `posts` method in User Model?

Comment: I assumed that you had defined a `posts` relationship in User Model but it seems that you have not.

Comment: In your user model create a relation with post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model create a relation like this

```
public function posts(){

    return $this->hasMany(Post::class,'author_id','id');

}
```

In your `Post` model create a relation like this

```
public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);

}
```

And replace this

```
if($deleteOption == "delete"){
    $admin->posts()->delete();
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'posts.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `posts` set `author_id` = 9, `posts`.`updated_at` = 2020-04-25 17:06:41 where `posts`.`user_id` = 8 and `posts`.`user_id` is not null)

Comment: it already named ad author_id in my posts table, relation to table users column id

Comment: Are posts table has `user_id` and `author_id` both??

Comment: hey its works, thank you. but again i have a new error, btw users not only have relationship with posts, users have relationship with ads, links, photos, which created by users. may you can give me some advice?

Comment: OK fine. Create more relationship like this in `User` Model and `Post` Model.  What advice you want to me